# How can I prevent thunderbird to start if the profile is missing?

Tags: thunderbird

I don't want thunderbird to start if a profile (folder) is missing. This works in my "old" thunderbird installation  (68.10.0), however on a new machine it automatically creates the missing profile (folder).

My old thunderbird installation behaves like this:

If the profile is not there, it does not start, instead it shows the following message:
"Your Thunderbird profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible."
And this is the desired behavior.

How can I prevent thunderbird to automatically create the profile folder path and create an new profile if the path is missing?

More precisely: How can I prevent thunderbird to start if the profile is missing?

Comment: *Your Thunderbird profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.* Never seen such an error with any Thunderbird releases even when the thunderbird folder is completely missing: in all cases a default profile has been created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the change in behaviour is documented here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_-_Thunderbird

> Profile Data protection
>
> Some users have multiple installations of Firefox on the same PC. The
> Firefox developers decided they wanted a dedicated profile per
> installation to make Firefox more stable when switching installations.
> This also makes it easier not to worry about backwards compatibility.
> Since Thunderbird uses the Mozilla Toolkit it inherited this feature
> in the version 68 beta.

I'm writing this answer as a Firefox user. However, the command-line options should transfer to Thunderbird, since it shares the dependencies as noted above.

New installations of Firefox and Thunderbird (68+, as noted above) come with a 'default' profile. It cannot be deleted as long as it is the only profile available. With that change, the concept of a 'missing' profile no longer applies. There is at least one profile available at any given time. Of course, you can manually corrupt the profile from its directory, in which case Firefox/Thunderbird would display an appropriate message.

There is no direct command-line option to revert to the old behaviour. However, a simple workaround is to use the `-ProfileManager` argument. This will bring up a Profile Manager window where you can manage your profiles (create/rename/delete). If your desired profile is not displayed, you can directly exit from the Profile Manager window without starting Firefox/Thunderbird.

You can find the full list of profile management arguments here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#User_Profile